# Render Action based on Enum Value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, enums, partial-views

In MVC5 controller, I do have a ActionResult which will display different reports as per users choice. I am doing it as following with no errors.

MainController:

```
    // POST: Report Init
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ShowReport(ReportUserInput userInput)
    {
        return View(userInput);
    }
```

ShowReport.cshtml [View File]:

```
@model App.ReportUserInput

<h2>ProjectBasedReport</h2>
@if(Model.rep_type == EnumOldReportTypes.ByGender)
{
    Html.RenderAction("ByGender", Model);
}
else if (Model.rep_type == EnumOldReportTypes.ByAddress)
{
    Html.RenderAction("ByAddress", Model);
}...
```

Here it works fine, I am only concerned with long if else, How can I call them without if condition something like:

```
HTML.%somefunction%
```

Comment: I don't think there is an out-of-the-box solution for your question. Your best bet might be defining your own helper for that matter. Or you could do some magic with custom attributes for enum members, but it sounds more like a nasty hack

Comment: Your going to need your `if else` somewhere, either in the controller, or the view, of in a HtmlHelper extension method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make your actions names same as your `enum`'s enumerators names. Then simply write following code instead of multiple if/else:

```
Html.RenderAction(Model.rep_type.ToString(), Model);
```

Or even if you can not match the `enum` and action names you could use a `Dictionary` to map your `enum` with proper action name:

```
var reportTypesActions=new Dictionary<EnumOldReportTypes, string> 
{ 
    { EnumOldReportTypes.ByAddress, "ActionNameOfByAddress" }, 
    { EnumOldReportTypes.ByGender, "ActionNameOfByGender" } 
};
```

Now you could write following code:

```
Html.RenderAction(reportTypesActions[Model.rep_type], Model);
```